# The least perfect square, which is divisible by each of 21,36 and 66 is (options)

Tags: divisibility, square-numbers

(a) 213444   
(b) 214344   
(c) 214434  
(d) 231444

Any short method to solve this question in 1 min?

Comment: The number must be divisible by $9$, $7$, $4$ and $11$. They all have the same bunch of digits, so there's no point pursuing $9$. Checking divisibility by $4$ (last two digits) eliminates (c). Checking divisibility by $11$ (alternate sum of digits) turns out to be rather easy: e.g. for (a), we have $(4-4) + (4-3) + (1-2) = 0$, while for (b) we have $(4-4) + (3-4) + (1-2)$ which is nonzero, and for (d) we again have $(4-4) + (4-1) + (3-2)$ nonzero as well. So it's (a).

Answer (score 2):

Only one of them is divisible by 7, so it has to be the answer. If you can do divisibility checks for these numbers in less than 1 min, that would suffice.

For example, you can do something like this rather quickly in your head:
$$
214434 = 210000 + 4434 \equiv 4434 = 4200 + 234 \equiv 234 = 210 + 24 \equiv 24 \not\equiv 0 \quad(\text{mod }7)
$$

Of course, if each number turned out to be divisible by e.g. 6, 7, 11 and other small factors of $\mathrm{lcm}(21,36,66)$, this method wouldn't be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Find LCM of $M=21,36,66$

$(1)$

Check for the prime factorization of $M$

If prime $p$ has odd index, multiply $M$ by $p$

Or
$(2)$

Check for the divisibility of the given numbers by $M$

Answer (score 0):

LCM of 21, 36, 66 is 3^2, 2^2, 7, 11. So the smallest perfect square should be 3^2 x 2^2 x 7^2 x 11^2 = 213444.

Comment: please format your answer with matjax